# Explanatory power of a variable

Tags: regression, importance

I have simple linear regression model. What I want to calculate is how "important" each of my input variables are i.e. to make a statement something like this:

"60% of predictive power in this model comes from variable var1, wheres var2 and var3 have30% and 10%" respectively"

What I need to do to calculate these percentages?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "predictive power"?  For instance, var3 might have extremely high correlation with the dependent variable in a sample but you might need to make predictions where var3 deviates substantially from the values it attained in the sample, thereby introducing huge uncertainty of prediction.  OTOH, var1 and var2 might individually have poor correlations with the DV, but together might work well for the intended predictions.  This indicates that measuring "predictive power" requires a specific *prediction context* in addition to the model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [relaimpo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html) R package does exactly what you want to do, and it also provides bootstrap CIs when assessing relative contribution of individual predictor to the overall $R^2$.

An example of use can be found at the end of this tutorial: [Getting Started with a Modern Approach to Regression](http://www.unt.edu/benchmarks/archives/2008/june08/rss.htm).

Comment: +1 for easy answer to miss formulated question. You should add that this only work if the number of predictor is smaller than, say, 50.

Comment: @chl The results (=order of importance of regressors) of RelaImpo vary drastically from the results of the unstandardized beta values. I wonder why that is - all my 14 regressors have the same metric (range 0 - 3), and although means and standard deviations vary drastically across symptoms, the unstandardized beta weights should give approximately similar results than RelaImpo, or not? Thank you.